# How to get Image Element from browser if I have the url?

Tags: javascript, browser

In my JavaScript I detect images that are on the page, amongst them those that are set as background images via "background-image:url" or "background" shorthand format.

I'd like to get the Image Element associated with that image, so I can check it's width/height and natural width/height.

Since the browser has already loaded these background images, is there are way to get the Image Element (or similar) associated with the loaded images so I can check the width/height and natural width/height.

Comment: It's Java via GWT....but pretty simple. A selector like this ([style*='background-image:url']) to get the element, then get it's style, from that the background-image, then parse out the URL. I now have the image url and would like to know width/height or natural width/height without re-downloading the image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd have to load the image into an element, and use `position: absolute` to position it off-screen, in order for it to have dimensions. Once the element is appended to the DOM you can retrieve the dimensions using `height()` and `width()`.

Comment: Thanks. Even though it is already shown in the browser as a background image to a DOM element?

Comment: That's how I understand it, yeah.

Comment: Do you think the browser will be smart enough to not download it, given that the image data has already been downloaded from that URL?

Comment: Ah, and that would only allow me to see the width/height that the image file has, not the width/height it is displayed at as the background image. But if there's no other way....

Comment: As far as its' size in the background... that depends on a few other things.. there's a newer background-size option for css... position, and repeat could also have effects... by default it *should* without scaling properties on the DIV be the native size (as in an img tag)

Comment: @Andrew if the server's configured sensibly, the browser should cache the image after loading it once.

Comment: @Tracker1 thanks. I guess there are many variables that can affect it, width/height properties on the tag its the background off, overflow-x/y properties, etc. The image could be larger than size given to the tag and clipped.... I'll investigate more. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Going to give a jQuery answer, and will expand if need be.  Straight JS would be a bit more difficult.  This presumes you *know* the URL for the image... since it's already loaded, simply place it into an image container.

```
//put the image into a container.
var d = $('<div style="position:absolute;overflow:hidden;height:1px;width:1px;padding-left:1px;background:transparent;>')
    .append($('<img src="..."/>').load(function(){
        //here you should be able to get the height/width
        var h = $(this).height();
        var w = $(this).width();

        //remove the container outside the event stack
        setTimeout(function(){
            d.remove();
        },0);
    })).appendTo('body');
```

Comment: Not using jQuery, but can follow that...so thanks. Again, will only get the source image size, not the displayed sized....but if that can't be done then this is useful. Thanks.

Comment: Tough call on who gets the answer....David answered and was very fast, but you supplied code.....  In the end I opted for the first explanation that was good enough for me to code myself....if I was using jQuery you might have got it! Sorry :-(

Answer (score -1):

You can loop through `document.getElementsByTagName("img")` and check the `src` attribute. If it matches your image url list, then you have the element.

To get the ones with the CSS background-image, you can loop through ALL the elements in the document and check if they have that style (`el.style["background-image"]`) or similar.

Comment: The image is not in an <img> tag, it is set as the background (via CSS) for another type of tag, such as <div>, <p> or <a>.

Comment: The insta-downvoting is really not cool. People often post-and-immediately-edit to expand (as I did to expand on the CSS solution). The other answers tell how to get the dimensions of a possibly unloaded image without redownloading, so mine is perhaps incomplete but not wrong or counterproductive.

Comment: I disagree somewhat. The original question states that the image is loaded as a background to a tag, and is not an <img> tag.....but if it's still bad form on StackOverflow then I'll take note.